# Using @min,@max and etc inside a predicate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

Is it possible to use aggregate operator such as @min inside a predicate?

BTW The predicate filters an array of objects.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY SELF.score == @min.score"];
```

I know you can retrieve the min value using the key-value operators eg:

```
NSNumber *minScore = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@min.score"];
```

So far I only get errors about the objects not being key value compliant for "@min".

Thanks

Comment: What are the objects in the array?

Comment: The objects are custom classes with an NSNumber property, and a nsmanagedobject. Score in this example is the NSNumber property.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that you're getting that error is that the predicate is being applied to each object in `myArray`, and those objects apparently don't support the key path `@min.score`. NSPredicate does have support for at least some of the collection operators, though. Here's a simple example that works:

```
NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:35] forKey:@"score"];
NSDictionary *d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:52] forKey:@"score"];
NSDictionary *d3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:13] forKey:@"score"];
NSDictionary *d4 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:19] forKey:@"score"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:d1, d2, d3, d4, nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.score == %@.@min.score", array];
NSLog(@"Min dictionaries: %@", [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]);
```

You can see that in this case, the `@min.score` key path is applied to the array, which makes sense. The output is an array containing the one dictionary that contains the minimum value:

```
Min dictionaries: (
        {
        score = 13;
    }
)
```

Comment: +1 But this requires us to filter a particular array and cannot be used for any other.

Comment: @Deepak, two things: 1) the array used in the predicate could easily be a parameter, so you could pass in any array; 2) I was trying to keep the example simple (and not spend too much time), but I believe that you could also apply the operator to a property of the thing being tested if that property is a collection. So, you could have a predicate like `@"SELF.games.@avg.score < %d"` if SELF.games is an array. The array being filtered might be an array of players, each of which has a `games` property. Such a predicate would select players with average score less than the value passed in %d.