# How to get a max value in using NSPredicate?

Tags: objective-c

I want to get a max value from below code.

Is it possible using a function like 'max()' in NSPredicate?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSNumber *number1 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:10];
        NSNumber *number2 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:20];
        NSNumber *number3 = [[NSNumber alloc]initWithInt:30];
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:number1, number2, number3, nil];

        NSArray *result = [array filterUsingPredicate:<#(NSPredicate *)#> <= How to get a max value?

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515167/using-min-max-and-etc-inside-a-predicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding maximum numeric value in NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080540/finding-maximum-numeric-value-in-nsarray)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use <s>KVO</s> KVC

```
NSNumber *result = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"];
```

Comment: It's actually KVC, not KVO.

Comment: And here is the [Key-Value Coding Collection Operators documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html)

Comment: Working link for [KVC Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE)