# NSFetchRequest, possible to filter by aggregate functions?

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

I am trying to pull all the `Actions` which belong to the latest `Session`.

In SQL this would be a simple JOIN ... WHERE Session.startTime = MAX(Session.startTime), but with Core Data I can't figure out how to do this without resorting to two steps as below. Any ideas?

```
// Step 1. Get the latest session

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Session" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:NO]]];
[request setFetchLimit:1];

Session *lastSession = nil;

NSArray *objects = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:NULL]; 

if ([objects count] > 0)
{ 
    NSLog(@"max: %@", [objects objectAtIndex:0]);
    lastSession = [objects objectAtIndex:0];
}

// Step 2. Get that session's actions

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Action" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sectionSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"session.startTime" ascending:NO selector:nil];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:NO selector:nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:sectionSort, sort, nil]];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"session.startTime = %@", lastSession.startTime];
//**Can't I do something like this instead?**
//NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"session.startTime = session.@max.startTime"];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

[self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"session.startTime" cacheName:@"ActionHistory"];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

NSError *error;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error])
{
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();  // Fail
}
```

Edit: I do need to stick with using `NSFetchedResultsController` due reasons not fully detailed above.

Comment: Hope this helps:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515167/using-min-max-and-etc-inside-a-predicate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515167/using-min-max-and-etc-inside-a-predicate

Comment: That is for filtering an array though, I want to filter a fetch request

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to make a relationship beetwen `Session` and `Action`.
Then, after you fetch the session you need, you could get all that session's actions as easy ss `lastSession.actions`.

**Edit**
Maybe you can do

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"session = %@",lastSession];
```

Comment: I do have a relationship between these two already. But by doing it like that, I couldn't use all the benefits of `NSFetchedResultsController's` anymore

Comment: But I will still need to get the lastSession separately first before I could use that predicate though