# How to find maximum id which is integer in a given NSSet through NSPredicate in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I am using `core data`.I have two entities.one is session and second is scan.here is one to many relationship, means one session can have multiple scans.

I have scans_id in scan Entity.Suppose in a session entity i have 3 scans means a `NSSet` of 3 scans.i want to find out that scan which is having maximum scans_id among the set.I want to do it from predicate.

I am using this function.

```
-(void)CallForGetMaximumScanIDInSession:(Session *)ObjTempSession
{
    NSSet *temp=ObjTempSession.scan;
    NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scans_id==max(scans_id)"];
    NSSet *setTemp = [temp filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSArray *arrTemp=[setTemp allObjects];

    if (arrTemp.coun>0 && arrTemp.coun==1)
    {
        // arrTemp must having a single object of scan.

    }
}
```

It is giving me crash on predicate line.

Please let me know if i am making wrong predicate.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the crash log saying?

Comment: this is the log report. -[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000011
2014-04-01 13:09:38.895 CattleTags[2489:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000011'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work i guess

```
NSSet *temp=ObjTempSession.scan;
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.scans_id == %@.@max.scans_id", temp];
```

You can find a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515167/using-min-max-and-etc-inside-a-predicate)

Comment: but now i am unable to fetch its properties. like in this way ObjScans.scans_id its giving me error that property "scans_id" cannot be found in class object "Scan".

Comment: what is ObjScans? Can you add your code and error log to the question